# Determining hidden attributes in Football Manager 2014

Tags: football-manager-2014

What are some easy ways to determine player's hidden attributes in Football Manager 2014? What actions should I undertake to reveal more about player's personality?

I mean only in-game fair ways, through direct or indirect interaction with the player.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

- use a in game editor like **FMRTE**
- use **FM Genie Scout** (best way in my opinion)

In this programs you can search by player and see all of his attributes, including the hidden ones and, in case of FM Genie Scout, the potencial ones!

With a simple google search you can easily find this two programs.

Comment: You have assumed that the asker wanted to cheat, I think you need to add any legitimate ways to do this in game without resorting to mods.

Comment: As per the question edit this answer no longer applies at all.